# sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:

Tags: build.gradle, gatling, gradlew, scala-gatling, gatling-plugin

I'm trying to implement gatling for a my project using gradle, I'm referring  [this blog](https://james-willett.com/2017/04/running-gatling-through-gradle/) to implement the same, it works very fine if I try to implement it as a individual project in intellij as per given in the blog.

But if I try to integrate the same with a project and add the plugin id for existing build,gradle then it gives me below error,

```
plugins {
    id "com.github.lkishalmi.gatling" version "0.3.0"
}


* What went wrong:
Error resolving plugin [id: 'com.github.lkishalmi.gatling', version: '0.3.0']
> Could not GET 'https://plugins.gradle.org/api/gradle/4.2.1/plugin/use/com.github.lkishalmi.gatling/0.3.0'.
   > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Not able to understand why its not working for integrating the project and working for individual one.

Could somebody please let me know how to deal with this problem,
I have been looking for solution and many places it is written that I will have to configure some certificate and many steps.

But I would not like to do that because if certificates was the problem then it should have been for individual project as well, if I remove the plugin `com.github.lkishalmi.gatling` then there would not be any problem, could there be any possibility because of other plugins, something is conflicting and then this issue is arriving.

I'm not able to understand the nature or logic of this issue, does it appears when there is something conflicting or its stand alone certificate problem.

In an individual project I tried adding the plugins from my project in that case it gave the same problem but for some added plugin like for adding below,

```
classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
classpath('org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.1')
```

So looking for the ways how can I go ahead with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could able to resolve the same by importing local network certificate, I tried to refer Jay's comments from the [this reference issue](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000094584-IDEA-Ultimate-2016-3-4-throwing-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target-when-trying-to-refresh-gradle?page=1#community_comment_360000110684) followed by setting up MAVEN_OPTS env variables and also I had to switch to unrestricted network solved my problem.